# IE css3 issue borders

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Hi I am trying to add a border to button in cshtml

```
.link:hover {
    border: solid #666000 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #666000 ;
    width: inherit;
}
```

but I am getting nothing in IE. any help?

Thanks

Comment: Add a jsfiddle, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

box shadow in IE need no prefixing

```
box-shadow: 1em 0.1em 0.5em 0.05em #666000;
```

or older IE you need -ms

```
ms-box-shadow: 1em 0.1em 0.5em 0.05em #666000;
```

firefox will need -Moz

```
-moz-box-shadow: 1em 0.1em 0.5em 0.05em #666000;
```

if you do not need the border line you need to remove this:

```
border: solid #666000 1px;
```

or you'll end up with a 1px black line around your .link and this is likely to hide your shadow if its really subtle.

-Website is only supported by Safari, Chrome, Opera.

Comment: This is unexpected acception, since in the OP there's a problem with `border` ... ; )

Comment: I stated if you need a border leave if not remove it, works for me fine :)

Comment: Your answer is fine, the question is just poorly worded.

Comment: Yes Thank you @AlanMorton2.0 I knew I had the border, and I had no problem with that rendering, it was just the shadow issue. I have no problems with the border, but either way iv removed it now. Thanks Again

Comment: @Teemu no worries, I tried to be clear.. but ok. the OP seems to have figured it all out now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use http://css3pie.com, which emulates some CSS3 properties in older versions of IE.

It supports box-shadow (except for the inset keyword).

OR

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='#c0c0c0')";
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='#c0c0c0');
```

Comment: Hi I only need to support IE9 upwards so im not sure ill need this?

Comment: yes it has, but it seems rather long winded as this will also work in IE 8 and 7 which I dont need thats all, box-shadow seems to have done the trick nicely :) but thanks, might come in handy on a legacy project.

Answer (score 0):

you try style like

```
.link:hover {
    border: solid #666000 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #666000 ;/* for chrome/safari */
    -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #666000 ;/* for FF */
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #666000 ;/* for IE*/
    width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, same as other answer, but still, thanks for you help :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: what do you want to say? i can not understand you @Ethaan